# Citation and reference to a figure: which comes first?

Tags: citations, thesis, writing, writing-style, cross-referencing

This may be a bit of hair-splitting, but maybe there is a proper way to do this: In my thesis I present an external application. I want to give a literature reference to the application and a reference to a screenshot. What comes first, the literature reference or the screenshot reference?

> The SuperFramework [1] (cf. Figure 1.1) ...

or

> The SuperFramework (cf. Figure 1.1) [1] ...

*Figure 1.1* is the screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to stick a citation and figure reference right next to one another in a non-ugly way, so I cheat.  When faced with a situation like this, I reorganize the sentence so that they are separated, e.g.:

> The SuperFramework [1], for which a screenshot is shown in Figure 1.1, ...

Answer (score 3):

If you have to go with either (and not with what jakebeal suggests), I would go with the first option:

> The SuperFramework [1] (cf. Figure 1.1) ...

I'm afraid I don't have any reference for this, it's just my copy editor hat on.

Comment: I agree with this. Placing the citation after the figure reference might give some readers that the citation is the source for the figure rather than the framework.

Comment: @Significance A source for a figure should be mentioned in the caption, not in the text.